# How to prevent ActiveRecord::Observer from logging deletion of dependent records if parent record is destroyed?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, callback, observer-pattern

I have a model User that has_one Company. A Company can have many Taxes and AdditionalFees. I am using ActiveRecord::Observer to log any activity done by the user on their Company data for the admin. For that purpose i am observing User, Company, Tax and AdditionalFee models. For any change made to the attributes in these models by the user i am logging these activities by creating a record in another ActivityLog model. 
The associations among my models are -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: :company, dependent: :destroy

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :user
  has_many: :taxes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many: :additional_fees, dependent: :destroy

class Tax < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :company

class AdditionalFee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :company
```

My Observer is as follows:

```
class ActivityObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :user, :company, :tax, :additional_fee
```

The problem i am facing is when the user or company is deleted.
I create a record in the AcitivityLog model in the **after_destroy** callback in my observer.

```
def after_destroy(obj)
  ActivityLog.create(performer: 'user_name_here', target: 'record_destroyed(serialised         object)', action: "destroy", description: "#user_name_here has deleted their company #company_name_here", change: "lot_variant")
end
```

*I create a record in the ActivityLog this way for each record in the observed model that is deleted.*

Because the observer is observing all the associated models, it is creating a new entry for each associated record when the user or company is deleted.

Is there a way to not prevent the observer from logging dependent destroyed records when the parent is destroyed? I do not wish to create a new entry in the ActivityLog model for the dependent records destroyed but want to record only for the parent record(company or user) that is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `obj` object type if it is `Company` or `User` you can go ahead and create `ActivityLog`.

```
def after_destroy(obj)
  case obj
    when Company, User then create_activity_log!
  end
end
```